# Selective Aggregation (GROUP BY specific rows in the table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have table where I need to group the amount for selective (specific rows).

Group by the rows from funds RLWP, RLNP/UL and RL Estate into a single row by Asset Name.

Rename the Fund Number Field to RP for > RLWP, RLNP/UL and RL Estate but I don’t want to group or sum where fund name not in (> RLWP, RLNP/UL and RL Estate)

```
Asset Name     |Entity Code  |Total SII Amount |Fund Number 
------------------------------------------------------------
GSW 4.375%     |1020OB       |1317697.53       |RLWP
GSW 4.375%     |1020OB       |1191368.74       |RLNP/UL
GSW 4.375%     |1020OB       |289004.18        |RL Estate
GSW 4.375%     |1020OB       |232360.70        |UFOIB
GSW 4.375%     |1020OB       |10102.50         |ABG
UKT 0.375%     |1020OB       |5555.20          |ABG
UKT 0.375%     |1020OB       |702743.3518      |RLWP
UKT 0.375%     |1020OB       |546232.3383      |RL Estate
```

I have 2 or 3 ways we can do it, But could you suggest the most efficient way as this is just one part of several other calculation on the same table in a stored procedure.

I think of one way is

```
Select 
    [Asset Name],
    [Entity Code],
    sum([Total SII Amount])
where 
    fundnumber in (RLWP, [RLNP/UL], RL Estate)
group by 
    [Asset Name], [Entity Code],

union

Select 
    [Asset Name],
    [Entity Code],
where 
    fundnumber not in (RLWP, [RLNP/UL], RL Estate)
```

And later update the column name to RP for (RLWP, [RLNP/UL] ,RL Estate).

Other way I think of using CTE or Cross Apply but Couldn’t really make up the query.

Please suggest.

Comment: which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: With SQL 2012 you should have a look on window functions. You can achieve a "running sum" using an OVER clause with ORDER BY and a grouped sum using PARTITION BY in the OVER clause...

Comment: @Shnugo Do you mean something like this :- SELECT [pK_AssetValuation],[Asset Name],[Entity Code],[Total SII Amount],FundNumber,
sum([Total SII Amount]) OVER(ORDER BY [FundNumber] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS RunningTotal
FROM tmpADSTransform1                                                      - But this just giving running total. I want to sum & group only few rows.

Comment: yes, try to add a PARTITION BY YourGroupColumn before the ORDER BY within the OVER without a commy :-)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, this could be an answer:

```
  SELECT [Asset Name],
         [Entity Code],
         SUM ([Total SII Amount]) [Total SII Amount],
         case  [Fund Number]
                when 'RLWP' then 'RP'
                when 'RLNP/UL' then 'RP'
                when 'RL Estate' then 'RP'
                else [Fund Number]
                end
            [Fund Number]
    FROM tab
GROUP BY [Asset Name],
         [Entity Code],
         case  [Fund Number]
                when 'RLWP' then 'RP'
                when 'RLNP/UL' then 'RP'
                when 'RL Estate' then 'RP'
                else [Fund Number]
                end
```

Comment: @PDSQL - this solves that problem the else causes those to be grouped by the fund number.

Comment: If Fund Number is ABG then you never want a sum? Not even when Asset Name and Entity Code is the same?

Comment: Thanks @Jon Tofte-Hansen What about the one without RL? like ABG - Shall I union them as I stated in my question. –  PD SQL

Comment: @JonTofte-Hansen Yes, if the FundNumber is not in ('RLWP' ,'RLNP/UL','RL Estate') No groouping or sum even when hen Asset Name and Entity Code is the same? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You asked me for an example, here you are: Just paste into an empty query window and execute, adapt to your needs...

```
DECLARE @Asset TABLE([Asset Name] VARCHAR(100),[Entity Code] VARCHAR(100), [Total SII Amount] DECIMAL(12,4),[Fund Number] VARCHAR(100) );
INSERT INTO @Asset VALUES
 ('GSW 4.375%','1020OB',1317697.53,'RLWP')
,('GSW 4.375%','1020OB',1191368.74,'RLNP/UL')
,('GSW 4.375%','1020OB',289004.18,'RL Estate')
,('GSW 4.375%','1020OB',232360.70,'UFOIB')
,('GSW 4.375%','1020OB',10102.50,'ABG')
,('UKT 0.375%','1020OB',5555.20,'ABG')
,('UKT 0.375%','1020OB',702743.3518,'RLWP')
,('UKT 0.375%','1020OB',546232.3383,'RL Estate');

--This comes back with all rows and a grouped sum at the end
WITH AssetsWithGroupedFundNumber AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CASE [Fund Number]
                WHEN 'RLWP' THEN 'RP'
                WHEN 'RLNP/UL' THEN 'RP'
                WHEN 'RL Estate' THEN 'RP'
                ELSE [Fund Number]
           END AS FundNumberGrouped
    FROM @Asset
)
SELECT *
      ,SUM(a.[Total SII Amount]) OVER(PARTITION BY a.FundNumberGrouped) AS GroupSum
FROM AssetsWithGroupedFundNumber AS a;

--This comes back with a "normal" grouped sum
WITH AssetsWithGroupedFundNumber AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CASE [Fund Number]
                WHEN 'RLWP' THEN 'RP'
                WHEN 'RLNP/UL' THEN 'RP'
                WHEN 'RL Estate' THEN 'RP'
                ELSE [Fund Number]
           END AS FundNumberGrouped
    FROM @Asset
)
SELECT a.FundNumberGrouped
      ,SUM(a.[Total SII Amount]) AS GroupSum
FROM AssetsWithGroupedFundNumber AS a
GROUP BY a.FundNumberGrouped
```

Comment: That quite helpful, I was using CTE so its inline with my code however I have to union all for FundNumber is not in ('RLWP' ,'RLNP/UL','RL Estate') i.e. for ABG - No grouping or sum  Required even when hen Asset Name and Entity Code is the same. I have just posted a protoType I have hundreds of  column in the table out of which many columns need to be summed.

Comment: @PDSQL If there is some unique rowID (whatever) you could change the "ELSE [Fund Number]" to this "ELSE [YourColumn]"  (could need a CAST to VARCHAR(100)!). This would come back with a unique grouping value for those rows you want to handle singularely.